# 'v-b-modal' and 'v-b-toggle' directives not working together

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

With this button options working only `v-b-toggle` directive. If comment one of them(either `v-b-modal` or `v-b-toggle`) everything works well(e.g. if comment toggle directive, modal directive starts working)

```
<b-button
    v-for="button in headerButtons"
    :key="button.name"
    :variant="button.variant"
    :class="`${button.class} mr-4`"
    v-b-modal="button.modalId"
    v-b-toggle="button.collapseId"
>{{ button.name }}</b-button>
```

data:

```
headerButtons: [
    {
        name: "btn 1",
        variant: "success",
        class: "green",
        modalId: "new-exchange-modal"
    },
    {
        name: "btn 2",
        variant: "info",
        collapseId: "search-collapse",
        class: "blue"
    }
]
```

What needs to be done to make all directives work?

**Note!** After hot reload(webpack) it works well(each of directives works fine together)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should switch to conditionally rendering buttons with only the required directives.  These two directives conflict with each other (mainly due to different ARIA markup added to the trigger buttons).

Do this instead:

```html
<tempate v-for="button in headerButtons">
  <b-button
    v-if="button.modalId"
    :key="button.name"
    :variant="button.variant"
    :class="`${button.class} mr-4`"
    v-b-modal="button.modalId"
  >{{ button.name }}</b-button>
  <b-button
    v-else-if="button.collapseId"
    :key="button.name"
    :variant="button.variant"
    :class="`${button.class} mr-4`"
    v-b-toggle="button.collapseId"
  >{{ button.name }}</b-button>
</template>
```

https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/4243